# Python sqlite3 database with varying number of columns?

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite

When using pythons sqlite3 module, if I were to create a table and the first row had say 4 columns would the next row have to have 4 columns or could I have more/less?

I'm looking to create a database of vocabulary words.  Each word may have a varying number of definitions.

For example 'set' would have many more definitions than 'panacea'.

I would work this vocabulary database in with a scraper that could easily look up the word and definition from a dictionary-reference site.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import sqlite3

def dictionary(word):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    response = br.open('http://www.dictionary.reference.com')
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['q'] = word 
    br.submit()
    definition = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())
    trans = definition.findAll('td',{'class':'td3n2'})
    fin = [i.text for i in trans]
    query = {}
    for i in fin: 
        query[fin.index(i)] = i

    ## The code above is given a word to look up and creates a 'dict' of its definiton from the site.

    connection = sqlite3.connect('vocab.db')
    with connection:
        spot = connection.cursor()

        ## This is where my uncertainty is.  I'm not sure if I should iterate over the dict values and 'INSERT' for each definition or if there is a way to put them in all at once? 

        spot.execute("CREATE TABLE Words(Name TEXT, Definition TEXT)")
        spot.execute("INSERT INTO Words VALUES(word, Definition (for each number of definitions))")

    return query


print dictionary(sys.argv[1])
```

This isn't an assignment but, more of a personal exercise for learning sqlite3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your design goes against the spirit of relational databases (where [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Relations_or_Tables) defines a relation as "a set of tuples that have **the same attributes**"), of which sqlite is one.

The appropriate design here is a table for words and a table for definitions, linked by a foreign key. If your word has no other attributes besides its content, you can get by with skipping the words table and just using the keys from the definitions table.

Note, however, that you'll have one row per definition, not one per word.

Comment: Thanks for responding first off!  With this technique, Tichodroma called it a '1-to-n' relation database, thats what this is?  What I'm picturing is one table containing 'Words' with Primary Keys matching to another table with 'definitions' each having its own row with a Primary Key matching the word in the first table?

Comment: My comments took awhile because my internet connection was dropping out.

Comment: I think @Tichodroma's answer sums up pretty neatly what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

> if I were to create a table and the first row had say 4 columns would the next row have to have 4 columns or could I have more/less?

You can't create a table where the rows have different numbers of cells in SQLite. You *can* put `Null` into a row's cell, though.

Perpahs you need a `1-to-n` relation: each word can have many definitions.

**Edit:**

Take a look at this diagram with two tables, `Word` and `Definiton`:

```
                +------------+
+-------+       | Definition |
| Word  |       +------------+
+-------+       | id PK      |
| id PK |-1---*-| word_id FK |
| text  |       | text       |
+-------+       +------------+
```

In both tables, `PK` is the *primary key* of the table. `FK` marks a *foreign key*, that is a column that references a PK of a *different* table. In this diagram, the FK `word_id` in `Definiton` references the PK `id` of `Word`. This relation is symbolized by the `-1---*-` connection between the two rows.

Comment: I not clear on what you mean(not much experience).  You are saying I could create rows based on the maximum number of definitions?  Where some 'words' would have a bunch of 'Null' cells?

Comment: You *could* do this but I advise against it. Use a 1-to-n relation as described in my or themel's answer.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer for the concept of the `1-to-n` relation.

Comment: Why not use just one key to match each other?  Or should I always use keys for every row when creating a table?